# Deploying aws-s3 to heroku,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

I've had no problem creating new companies on my heroku site. When I added aws-s3 to store the photos I started running into this error.

```
Paperclip::Error (Company model missing required attr_accessor for 'logo_image_file_name')
```

In my schema, my companies table has logo_image_file_name and my corresponding controller has

```
params.require(:company).permit(:name, logo_image: 
[:logo_image_file_name, :logo_image_file_size, 
:logo_image_content_type, :logo_image_updated_at], :address...
```

I've done heroku rake db:reset and seeded the database. The error has so far only occurred on company form submission.

Comment: Is that error apear only when seeding the database ??

Answer (score 0):

**Try Updating Heroku**

Run the following lines in your console/terminal

```
$ heroku run rake:db:migrate

$ heroku restart
```

Faced the same issue and got resolved after updating it.

Comment: I've fixed the issue. It was a rake task solution.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS)

Comment: The other solutions I've found on here say it's either a problem with Paperclip or aws-s3.

Comment: @Coder_Nick :its aws-sdk version issue

Comment: Please have a look at this discussion this may help you : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/1764